# Video Size Calculation

Tags: video, video-encoding

I am trying to calculate how much space the following video will require:

704x576 size, with 30 frames per second, running for a 90 minute length, and has 24 bit per pixel color coding. The video is in an uncompressed raw format.

I am not sure if I am doing the math correctly:

```
704*576 = 405504 bytes * 30 fps = 12165120 byte = 12.165Mbps
```

However, I do not understand how the 24 bit per pixel should be incorporated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. There are 8 bits in a byte, so 24 bits per pixel implies 3 bytes per pixel.
2. There are 1024² bytes in a megabyte.
3. 'MB' is megabytes, 'Mb' is megabits. Don't conflate them, because you'll be off by a factor of 8.

The math then is:

> 704 × 576 pixels × 3 bytes per pixel × 30 frames per second ÷ (1024 × 1024 bytes per megabyte) ≅ **34.8 MB/s** = 278.4 Mb/s.
>
> Total data = 34.8 MB/s × 60 seconds per minute × 90 minutes ÷ (1024 megabytes per gigabyte) ≅ **183.5 GB**.

(Note: Most applications prefer to use 32 bits per pixel *in memory* for 24-bit colors, because the power of two size is easier to work with. It would be overly wasteful if they did that in a file, but if you find the actual data usage is a third greater than it should be, then it may be writing 32 bits per pixel despite the fact that only 24 of those have useful color data. You can look at the data in a hex editor to confirm; you will see it has a pattern that repeats every 3 bytes or every 4 bytes.)

Comment: In reality, digital video is usually not stored or transmitted in raw form. It uses lossy compression standards such as MPEG4 so that most frames encode only the differences from the previous frames. There's also spatial compression within a frame since neighbouring pixels are correlated. So a 90-min video will take a lot less space than 183 GB.